# SQL query issues realted to alias

Tags: mysql, sql

Please can someone help me solve this problem;

So I got this SQL Query;

```
SELECT Route.Number FROM ROUTE INNER JOIN Operator ON Operator.Name =
Route.Operatedby INNER JOIN Operator ON Operator.Name = Route.OperatorName 
WHERE Operator.Description = "Fawcal";
```

this is the error I get;

```
Not Unique table/alias
```

Comment: You are joining same table twice you need to use alias name.

Comment: 'Fawcal' perhaps? (Single quotes instead of double quotes.)

Comment: sorry that was a typo it should be Operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are joining the same table twice so use `Alias`

```
SELECT r.Number 
FROM 
    ROUTE  r INNER JOIN Operator o 
        ON o.Name = r.Operatedby  
    INNER JOIN Operator o2 
        ON o2.Name = r.OperatorName 
WHERE o.Description = "Fawcal";
```

Comment: @sgeddes Yes I know. I just assumed that it was typo due to error and similarity between table names. And OP is also commented That.

Comment: THis works, but can i ask is there anyway I could get to see the both of the result ? so atm I can only see WHERE o.Description = "Fawcal"; .. I can't see the o2

Comment: Add the where condition as `o2.Description= "Fawcal" `